# Java thread-safe collection for a get-size-and-delete-element pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency

I have a list of strings shared between a number of threads. Each thread has to:

1. access the list (for example via a getter method);
2. get the size of the list;
3. choose a random number n between zero and list.size();
4. extract the element at offset n from the list;
5. delete the extracted element from the list;
6. "save" the list back so that other threads view always the updated list

Since there is a concurrent access to a mutable shared object (the list), I need to code in a thread-safe way. Each thread has to diminish the list size by one and for this reason every other thread access must see a shorter list. My aim is to avoid a thread can see the *same* list seen by another thread, because in this way there is the possibility that the same element could be extracted twice.

Which is the best way to accomplish this? I was thinking about CopyOnWriteArrayList but I'm not sure it behaves like I need.

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that operations 1 to 6 need to be atomic and using a CopyOnWriteArrayList won't solve that.

One solution is to simply synchronize the whole operation:

```
private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String> ();
public String getNextItem() {
    synchronized(list) {
        //get the string adn remove it from the list
    }
    return next;
}
```

Alternatively, you could review your algorithm and do something like:

- create the list
- shuffle it (to introduce randomness)
- populate a BlockingQueue with that list (for example a [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html))
- have your threads [take items](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) from the queue (thread safe atomic operation => no additional synchronization required)

Comment: like your alternative approach :)

Comment: the BlockingQueue approach seems simpler, because then I would have no need to save back an updated version of the list. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why you cannot put the above sequence of logic in a synchronize block, or using semaphore/mutex for exclusive access to list during the above sequence of logic.